# <object> doesn't appear when data=google.co.uk

Tags: html, object

I want to embed the google home page in a page on my website. I want to use the `<object>` html5 element because from what I've read this is the most up-to-date way to do this and should work on ie7+ and everything else.

But I'm having problems getting it to work. Here's what I'm using:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.google.co.uk" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></object>
```

If I change the url to something different it works fine, but with google... nothing.

Am I missing something? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is the most up-to-date way

It isn't. `<object>` is simply a generic way. It is inconsistently supported.

If you want to embed HTML documents, use an iframe.

That won't help in *this* situation though. In the HTTP headers for the page, Google say:

> `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

They are forbidding you from embedding their page inside yours, and your browser is respecting their wishes.

Comment: I wonder if there's a good way to do this that comes easily to your mind? Basically I want people to be able to browse to a site and bookmark it. All within my site somehow. Either that or I need them to copy and paste urls into a form on my site which isn't so great. I kinda just want an easy way for a user to select a website url and save it to my site - browsing to the site seems the nicest way to do that

Comment: Bookmarklet that they run from their bookmark bar during normal browsing.

Comment: After a bit of reading I can see this is a nice solution, however for my particular purpose it's not ideal. I reckon I could use a Custom Google Search Engine CSE and that way still have a google within a page on my site. The only thing is, is there a way to get the url of whatever page the user is currently visiting in the <object> part of the page?

Comment: No. You can't communicate across frames on different domains (unless they co-operate to make it possible, which won't be the case with Joe Random Web Site)